# convert float to hours using momentjs

Tags: momentjs

For example, how to convert this float number 6.5 to "06:30" using momentjs?

I've tried this:

```
moment("6.5", "hh:mm").format("HH:mm"))
```

but it outputs:

```
06:05
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to convert your `float` to string you can create a [duration](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) object and then display it as string using [moment-duration-format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/duration-format/) plug-in.

Here a working example:

```js
var dur = moment.duration(6.5, 'h');
console.log(dur.format('HH:mm'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/1.3.0/moment-duration-format.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is not working (anymore?). Duration object has no format property.
See working answer below.

Comment: @ppulwey code proposed in the answer still works ;) Duration object has no format property, but, as stated in the answer, [moment-duration-format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/duration-format/) *plug-in* adds `format` method to duration. Feel free to upvote/use the solution that best fits your needs

Comment: Sorry for that! :/

Answer (score 2):

You can do that without additional library (only with Moment.js) if you use the code snippet below:

```
moment.utc(moment.duration(6.5, 'h').asMilliseconds()).format('HH:mm')
```

It's important to use moment.utc as a wrapper of duration in milliseconds because if you use the common moment it will calculate timezone difference as well and you'll get the final result wrong.